# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type - typedef struct

Tags: c, database, struct, error-handling, typedef

I am looking for an error in my code (in C) and I am not finding anything.
I've looked on many blogs and tried many things that were advised but nothing helped.
I've coded that :

```
typedef struct Account_t *Account;
struct Account_t {
     Customer customer;
     Realtor realtor;
     Offer offer;
};
```

while Realtor, Customer and Offer are well defined and included with a .h file. I am getting an error that says "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct Account_t' " when I write:

```
 Account account = malloc(sizeof(*account));
```

Please help me find the problem !

Comment: That should be valid (see [here](http://ideone.com/v19S9v)). Please post a complete example. For some reason, the compiler hasn't seen the struct definition at the time you're using `malloc`.

Comment: Show defining of  `Customer`, `Realtor`  and `Offer`.

Comment: _...while Realtor, Customer and Offer are well defined..._   Can you include them into your post?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Compile problem, should be handled with correct type conversion and correct type allocation. Taking in consideration that Account is declares as pointer to Account_t, see the typedef, the correct sizeof should be taken from Account_t or Account* or *account. But pointer conversion to Account.
I'd say, you have to do something like this:

```
Account account = (Account)malloc(sizeof(*account));
```

Comment: `sizeof(account)` will return the size of a pointer (8 or 4 bytes). `sizeof(*account)` will return `sizeof(Account_t)`

Comment: In fact this was exactly the intention. The user that posted the question was, did not formulate that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code out. And I had similar issue as you.

The problem is with your code, when you allocate the structure in the heap, the returned value is wrong assigned, because the malloc returns a pointer.

my code looks like this:

```
Account* account = (account*)malloc(sizeof(account));
```

And second thing:
As type definition I do not define the structure as a pointer.

```
typedef struct account_t Account;
```

Try this, I hope this information useful!